# Using dates to cycle through (query) my localStorage. Difficult times with the date object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm using my localStorage to stored data based on dates. I think (I thought!) it was quite elegant.

Data goes in like this:

```
localStorage.setItem(datakey, JSON.stringify(dataObject));
```

and I get it out like this

```
dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(datakey));
```

So as you can see, the datakey is the primary key. And I'm using a formatted date for it. The data is in a DD/MM/YY format, and I get it (thanks to StackOverflow) like this:

```
Date.prototype.getDateKey = function() {
    function two(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }
    return two(this.getDate()) + '/' + two(this.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + this.getFullYear();
};

var d       = new Date();
var datakey = d.getDateKey();
```

So now what I want to do is use another variable to "search" the localStorage and pull ALL the data between two dates (today and a point in the past). I've tried this:

```
 function getData(timespan){
    var period  = timespan;
var start_date  = d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-timespan);
var today_key   = d.getDateKey();
var history_key = start_date.getDateKey();
 }
```

to no avail.

I want to cycle through the dates, day by day but start_date is not a date object for some reason and therefore does not have the getDateKey() method. I planned to use a for loop to cycle from history_key to today_key and each time get the localStorage data thus:

```
dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(i));
```

and then stick the results in an array which I can than pull the data from.

Main problem: how to cycle through the dates and get them into i so I get the data from localStorage. start_date isn't an object (according to the console and typeof) so I'm kind of stuck.

Sorry for the long explanation but if I'm explicit about what I'm trying to do it's probably easier for people to see what the point of all this is, and maybe tell me I'm mad for doing x or y or for using localStorage like this.

Anyone any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

`Date.setMonth()` does not return a `Date` object. In fact, it returns nothing. You are thinking of dates as if they were strings, which are immutable. Dates are mutable, so...:

```
function getStartDate(timespan) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-timespan);
    return date;
}

var today = (new Date()).valueOf(); //milliseconds
function getNextDate(currentDate) {
    //get the next day:
   currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);
   var finish = currentDate.valueOf() > today;
   return finish ? null : currentDate;
}


var currentDate = getStartDate(1); //let's say, one month ago.
var dataObjects = [];
do {
    var storedItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(currentDate.getDateKey()));
    if (storedItem) dataObjects.push(storedItem);
} while (currentDate = getNextDate(currentDate));
```

This is the idea. Hope it serves you.

**EDIT**

Basically, I set a `currentDate`, a date defined by today and the timespan you pass `getStartDate()`. Then I store the milliseconds reprensenting today. This way, the function `getNextDate()` will check whether the increasing dates are greater that today. If they are, the process stops.

There is no reason gor `getNextDate()` to return `currentDate`. It is a global variable and, besides, the function already modifies its value, not the reference itself. I do it for aesthethic purposes. I have to return something, and, as the function is called `getNextDate()`, it is logical that it returns the next date ... except if that date is greater that today, in that case I return `null`. When I return `null`, the expression

```
curentDate = getNextDate(currentDate)
```

is equal to `null` (assignment is an expression thar returns the value the l-value receives, that's why expressions like `a = b = c = 10;` work) and the `do ... while` loop ends.

By the way, the error you found was because I forgot to pass `getNextDate()` the current date. Now it should work.

Try it, and if you find errors, tell me.

Comment: I'm confused by the last line - "while (currentDate = getNextDate()); Should that be "="? Can you explain to me how this entire code works? It looks like if does all the things in the do clause whilst the currentDate is equal to the returned value from getNextDate() and that the getNextDate function returns currentDate up until the finish var is null (when currentDate.valueOf() is greater than today. Sorry, I just like to walk through things. I think I get it but I still don't know why I was wrong.

Comment: I've tried it and I get a console error: "Cannot call method 'getDate' of undefined" on the line - currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);